# CDI Inject Ambiguous Dependency "pick any, i don't care"

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

One of my classes has an attribute declared with the @EJB annotation.
Two beans are eligible, so I get a nice `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies`.

I know this can be resolved with qualifiers. But that would make me select one EJB implementation over the other. But I don't really care which one is used. Is there a simple way to tell CDI "Pick any of the two eligible implementations, I don't care and both are fine" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... a simple way to tell CDI "Pick any of the two eligible implementations, I don't care and both are fine"

**No there is not**. That would be against what CDI tries to achieve. Here is a peak at why is that...

One case might be that your beans are for instance session beans. In such case, having two fitting beans for that injection points doesn't mean that both of them even *exist* within that given moment you request them. Needless to say they might not carry the data/state you expect them to have.

Another reason is that CDI has an underlying proxy system - each `@Inject`ed bean is in fact the proxy object of that bean. To avoid weird NPEs and exceptions during runtime, CDI needs to know, at boot time, what will be the **one** fitting bean for your injection point.

Another point might be the different lifecycle management of beans you could inject. That would yield you even weirder runtime errors.

Last but not least, imagine your app growing bigger. Someone adds third implementation of the type you are injection and that one is **not fine** for what you want to achieve. What would happen then?

That would be it from the top of my head. As for the way to go, you can use `Instance<MyBean>` or resolution via `BeanManager`. Below is a snippet with `Instance` which is probably a better way.

```
@Inject
private Instance<Foo> foo;

public void doStuff() {
  foo.isAmbiguous(); //you can check if there are more beans eligible for injection here
  foo.isResolvable(); //yet another useful check you might want

  // there are multiple selects you can use - based on type, annotation or both
  //select based on annotation (parameter is annotation INSTANCE), with this you require a Foo type with @Default qualifier
  foo.select(Default.Literal.INSTANCE).get();

  //select based on requested type, here you are asking for a Foo bean which also has a type MyType (implements interface or extends class with that type for instance)
  foo.select(MyType.class).get(); 

  // combined - type and annotation
  foo.select(MyType.class, Default.Literal.INSTANCE).get();
}
```

*NOTE:* When working with `Instance<X>` the method `get()` is what does the actual resolution and gives you the resulting bean.

Comment: As `Instance<X>` extends `Iterable<X>`, why not use the first that gets returned by the iterator? By doing that, you don't need to know the exact subclass of X to be used with `select()`.

Comment: For the reasons stated in comment - you cannot be sure what you get. Not all beans you get will be fitting for the purpose you want them for. It is far more safer to just pick one implementation and use that. As well as you say "pick any" why not say "always pick this one".

Comment: Quoting the original question: "But I don't really care which one is used". So picking any implementation is totally doable without having to decide on a specific subclass/qualifier (this becomes really useful when your architecture allows plugins). Moreover, your use of `select()` is wrong as it shouldn't get a qualifier class but an instance of that qualifier as parameter. The only class parameter for `select()` should be a subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: My answer was trying to explain that saying "But I don't really care which one is used" might not be the best approach. The reasons for that are listed in the answer. And since it was accepted, I presume it was sufficient. Sorry, I am afraid I cannot really see what are you arguing here about?
As for the `Qualifier`, yea you are right made a mistake there. Thanks, will change the snippet right away.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with `Instance<X>`:

```
@Inject
private Instance<MyEjb> myEjbs;

public void myMethod() {
    MyEjb myEjb = myEjbs.iterator().next();
    myEjb.doSomething();
}
```